# Add styles to AmCharts 4 labels

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have a cylinder bar chart in AmCharts 4 that uses a darker color scheme.  The text color for the labels on the bars is black and is not really showing on darker colors.

*- I am using the javascript code illustrated in AmChart's Demos for the Cylinder 3D Chart.*

[image: Dark Chart with unreadable labels]

Is there a way to add css to the label/label text?

I would like to add a white text-shadow to the label to make it readable.  Also, this way, it won't affect the text when it is over the white chart background.

Edit: 12/18/2018 - I am looking for the text to be closer to something like this:
[image: Readable Chart Labels]

These will be able to be seen, even if the bar is short and the text lays against the white background.

Comment: I assume it's using svg and plopping it in a transformed svg `text` element. So could do css like `svg text { color: red; background-color: white }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could set fill to the labels template:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
```

Please check the example here: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3446cd09288ee4e5901c73b3970adbfe?editors=0010

Comment: The issue with this is that the text gets lost in the white background on columns that have short bars that do provide a backdrop for the text.

Comment: You could try `labelTemplate.background.fill = am4core.color("#000");` or juggle with the fill and [fillOpacity](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#fillOpacity_property) values. Please check the updated example.

Comment: This should do the trick.  I will see if I can "soften" the edges on the background and give it a slight radius.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Eric You can also try fiddling around with a [`DropShadowFilter`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dropshadowfilter/#constructor_method), e.g. `var shadow = labelTemplate.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
shadow.dx = 0;
shadow.dy = 0;`. More on filters: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-filters/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to add a white stroke to SVG text. First enable CSS classes for amCharts 4:

```
am4core.options.autoSetClassName = true;
```

And then add this to your CSS:

```css
@supports (paint-order: stroke) {
  .amcharts-LabelBullet text {
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    stroke-linecap: butt;
    stroke-linejoin: miter;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

This will add a 4px white outline to all LabelBullet text.